# Losing data due to specific screen rotations android

Tags: android

READ BEFORE YOU DOWN VOTE

Hello

I currently have a problem: data is being lost upon specific screen rotation,
portrait to landscape: I lose no data.
landscape to portrait: I lose data.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    getStringFromArray(puzzle);
    getSharedPreferences("firstrun", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("current", currentstring).commit();
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    currentstring = getSharedPreferences("firstrun", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("current", "1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1");
    getArrayFromString(currentstring);
}
```

The only sense I can make from this is that the onCreate() method is recalled when going from landscape to portrait however not from portrait to landscape.
It must also somehow save the initial variable past to the activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    KEY_DIFFICULTY = getIntent().getStringExtra((String) KEY_DIFFICULTY);
    Log.d("PANIC HERE", "" + KEY_DIFFICULTY);

    if (getSharedPreferences("firstrun", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("firstrun", true)) {
        String easy1 = ""+
                "null,null,null,null,null,null,7,2,null," +
                "3,7,null,null,null,9,null,1,null," +
                "1,null,8,3,7,null,null,null,null," +
                "8,null,null,5,null,null,2,null,6," +
                "null,2,4,null,3,null,1,9,null," +
                "7,null,6,null,null,4,null,null,8," +
                "null,null,null,null,2,6,5,null,1," +
                "null,6,null,8,null,null,null,7,4," +
                "null,1,5,null,null,null,null,null,null";
        getSharedPreferences("firstrun", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("easy1", easy1).commit();
        getSharedPreferences("firstrun", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("easy2", "null").commit();
        getSharedPreferences("firstrun", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("easy3", "null").commit();

        getSharedPreferences("firstrun", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("medium1", "null").commit();
        getSharedPreferences("firstrun", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("medium2", "null").commit();
        getSharedPreferences("firstrun", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("medium3", "null").commit();

        getSharedPreferences("firstrun", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("hard1", "null").commit();
        getSharedPreferences("firstrun", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("hard2", "null").commit();
        getSharedPreferences("firstrun", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("hard3", "null").commit();

        getSharedPreferences("firstrun", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("current", "null").commit();

        getSharedPreferences("firstrun", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();
    }

    if(KEY_DIFFICULTY != null){
        puzstring = KEY_DIFFICULTY +"1";
        currentstring = getSharedPreferences("firstrun", MODE_PRIVATE).getString(puzstring, "1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1");
        getSharedPreferences("firstrun", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("current", currentstring).commit();
    }else{
        currentstring = getSharedPreferences("firstrun", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("current", "1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1");
    }
    getArrayFromString(currentstring);
    grid = new GridView(this);
    setContentView(grid);
    grid.requestFocus();
    startpuzzle = puzzle;
}
```

Comment: Also yes I want to use shared preferences as I will be editing these preferences with a service later on. So please don't recommend changing this

Comment: my problem is the oncreate method is being called every time with the same intent that was initially stored, I guess I will have to use onConfigurationChanged to stop the oncreate being called over and over

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sounds weird, however I think you must override the methods `onPause` and `onResume` because when you rotate the screen these methods will be invoked so you must store your state when the screen is rotated (`onPause`) and restore the state when the screen is redrawn (`onResume`). 
Please read more about the activity lifecycle http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html, it's very important to know how it works.

Comment: I have tried overwriting both of those, I had the same issue and they seemed irrelevant when I removed them

Comment: my problem is the oncreate method is being called every time with the same intent that was initially stored, I guess I will have to use onConfigurationChanged to stop the oncreate being called over and over

Answer (score 0):

The onDestroy() method was called when the phone turned landscape to portrait however not when turning from portrait to landscape.
The onCreate() method was being called only when the activity was destroyed.